# "set-cookie" header in webviews with Android sdk 31

Tags: android, cookies, webview, setcookie, jsessionid

As reported here:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12

starting with sdk 31 we had to add **"SameSite= None; Secure"** to every single cookie inside the cookie string, otherwise the browser would cut the session cookie during cross-site requests.

Now, the problem occurs when the response of an API has "**set-cookie**" in its header.

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=x1231hjg12u4fg1ijkg41:j4h1sjns;
```

In this particular case, the new JSESSIONID session cookie will not be added as the attribute "SameSite= None; Secure" is not set.

Is there any way client-side to add the new cookie?